# order page throws error saying undefined index.

Tags: orders, magento-1.9.2.0

I work with magento 1.9.2.2 and i get this error on loading page for order.

```
Notice: Undefined index: mpassignproduct_id  in /var/www/app/design /adminhtml/default/default/template/marketplace/sales/items/column/name.phtml
```

Iam using webkul marketplace. Even if nobody can help in such custom modules, please tell me what this error means.

Answer (score 0):

Notice errors shouldn't be enabled on your production store. They should be fixed, but since they are not critical, many developers just decide to ignore them.

Open your root `index.php` and change your `error_reporting` declaration to this one:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

It should escape notice errors.

Comment: thank you for feedback, yet i have to search for my answer

Comment: Your error is explicitly described in the message. It tells you the exact file, and the exact reference that is throwing the notice error. It's probably trying to access the array key when it doesn't exist. But my advice would be to apply the solution I have described above, if you update your module, your custom changes would disappear.

Comment: this is the another error i got. Undefined index: INR  in /var/www/app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Saleslist.php on line 281

Comment: Please read my answer. You will get hundreds of notice errors because extensions don't take them in account, just disable them.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your issue ;)